# Facebook login button on a swipeview fragemt - Facebook SDK 4.12.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I am getting the following exception when adding the Login button on my fragment:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML
>   file line #6: Error inflating class
>   com.facebook.login.widget.DeviceLoginButton
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                        at
>   brudner.com.pension.fragments.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:28)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Here is the MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
            private ViewPager viewPager;
            private SwipeAdapter adapter;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                initSharedPrefs();
                FacebookManager.initFacebook();
                initView();
            }

            private void initView() {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                setupViewPager(viewPager);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                if (tabLayout != null)
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            }

            private void initSharedPrefs() {
                new SharedPrefsManager(getSharedPreferences("myApp", MODE_PRIVATE));
                SetDate(false);
            }

            private void SetDate(boolean iReset) {
                if (SharedPrefsManager.getManager().getLong("UnixTime", 0)   > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() || iReset)
                {
                    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatepickerFragment();
                    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                date.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                date.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                if(DateManager.SaveDate(date.getTimeInMillis()))
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Date was set: "+date.getTimeInMillis(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Date was NOT set: "+date.getTimeInMillis(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
                adapter = new SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                adapter.AddFragment(new MainFragment(), "MAIN");
                adapter.AddFragment(new DaysFragment(), "DAYS");
                adapter.AddFragment(new SecondsFragment(), "SECONDS");
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.setDate:
                        SetDate(true);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                        // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
            }

        }
```

Here is the fragment_main xml:

```
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/myProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the Activity_main xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="center"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Once I remove the LoginButton from the fragment_main.xml it works well.

What am I missing here?
Thank you very much!